# How to fix this cmd scripting string parsing error

Tags: cmd, windows-7

My system path is:

```
C:\Users\angus\algs4\java\bin;C:\binaryTools\SMLNJ\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Scripts\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\binaryTools;C:\Program Files (x86)\ActiveState Komodo IDE 8\;C:\PHP\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell Platform\2012.4.0.0\lib\extralibs\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell Platform\2012.4.0.0\bin;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin;c:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;c:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Services\IPT\;c:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\NTRU Cryptosystems\NTRU TCG Software Stack\bin\;C:\Program Files\NTRU Cryptosystems\NTRU TCG Software Stack\bin\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell Platform\2012.4.0.0\mingw\bin;C:\Python33;C:\Python33\Scripts;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Platform SDK\Bin\.;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Platform SDK\Bin\WinNT\.;C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Collaborator Client;C:\Program Files\doxygen\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;
```

And I am trying to update a registry key (the system path) using a script but am getting a wierd error:

```
>myscript.cmd
\Python36-32\Scripts\ was unexpected at this time.
```

How can I fix the script error?

Here is the script:

```
echo off

SET PROGPATH=C:\dell\mypath

for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('REG QUERY "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v Path') do set "SysPath=%%~b"

echo system path is: %SysPath%

echo %SysPath%>tmppath.txt

echo %PATH% | findstr /i %PROGPATH%
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 (
   echo %PROGPATH% path not found in system path

   REM we now add to syspath and then write back to registry
    set UPDATEDPATH=%PROGPATH%;%SysPath%

   REM we now just write UPDATEDPATH back to registry
   REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /f /v "Path" /t REG_SZ /d "%UPDATEDPATH%" 

    echo %PROGPATH% should now be added to the system path
) else (
   echo %PROGPATH% already in path
)
```

The problem line is: echo %PATH% | grep %PROGPATH%

you get the error wherever there is a

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin;
```

or something like that.

ie the  (x86)\J or  (x86)\P etc

So how to fix that?

Was asked for more details.  So here.

Before running script, my env is like this:

keyname:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment
```

Path key has value:

```
C:\Users\angus\algs4\java\bin;C:\binaryTools\SMLNJ\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Scripts\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\binaryTools;C:\Program Files (x86)\ActiveState Komodo IDE 8\;C:\PHP\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell Platform\2012.4.0.0\lib\extralibs\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell Platform\2012.4.0.0\bin;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin;c:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;c:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Services\IPT\;c:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\NTRU Cryptosystems\NTRU TCG Software Stack\bin\;C:\Program Files\NTRU Cryptosystems\NTRU TCG Software Stack\bin\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell Platform\2012.4.0.0\mingw\bin;C:\Python33;C:\Python33\Scripts;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Platform SDK\Bin\.;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Platform SDK\Bin\WinNT\.;C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Collaborator Client;C:\Program Files\doxygen\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;


>echo %PATH%
C:\Users\angus\algs4\java\bin;C:\binaryTools\SMLNJ\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Scripts\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\binaryTools;C:\Program Files (x86)\ActiveState Komodo IDE 8\;C:\PHP\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell Platform\2012.4.0.0\lib\extralibs\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell Platform\2012.4.0.0\bin;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin;c:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;c:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Services\IPT\;c:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\NTRU Cryptosystems\NTRU TCG Software Stack\bin\;C:\Program Files\NTRU Cryptosystems\NTRU TCG Software Stack\bin\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell Platform\2012.4.0.0\mingw\bin;C:\Python33;C:\Python33\Scripts;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Platform SDK\Bin\.;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Platform SDK\Bin\WinNT\.;C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Collaborator Client;C:\Program Files\doxygen\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Users\angus\algs4\bin;C:\Users\angus\algs4\java\bin;C:\Users\angus\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Platform SDK\Bin\.;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Platform SDK\Bin\WinNT\.;C:\binaryTools\emacs-24.5-bin-i686-mingw32\bin;C:\windows;C:\windows\system32;C:\Users\angus\AppData\Roaming\Dashlane\4.7.1.28771\bin\Firefox_Extension\{442718d9-475e-452a-b3e1-fb1ee16b8e9f}\components;C:\Users\angus\AppData\Roaming\Dashlane\4.7.1.28771\ucrt
```

now if I run the batch file contents above which I named path3.cmd I get:

```
>path3.cmd
\Python36-32\Scripts\ was unexpected at this time.

>
```

Trying

```
echo %PATH% | findstr /i /c:"%PROGPATH%"
```

or

```
echo "%PATH%" | findstr /i /c:"%PROGPATH%"
```

makes no difference.

The bug seems to be in this line:

```
set UPDATEDPATH=%PROGPATH%;%SysPath%
```

Comment: The first thing to do is to get rid of `echo off` so you can see which line is failing.  If that doesn't make the problem obvious, post the output.

Comment: You are aware of the fact that your path has 50 entries? `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin` is doubled and there are several outdated versions of tools? And you want to add one more to slow your computer down another step? Weird, there is maintenance needed.

Comment: The brackets in the PATH shouldn't matter, and I've tried the line in question on my system and it works fine; are there brackets in PROGPATH?  Try something like `echo %PATH% | findstr /i /c:"%PROGPATH%"`

Comment: ... are you sure the code as posted is exactly the same as the code you're using?  Can you post the output please?